# Repeat regex capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex which captures two different capturing groups repeatedly. I have text pointers in my project like |:framework.urls.http:| and I need to be able to create a regex to find when there are urls in a string via these text pointers. They will always start with |:framework.urls.*something*:|

They may be up against other text pointers, or they may be up against any character that is NOT a space because we won't allow any spaces in our URLs in the text. Here is a regexer of my attempted solution: http://regexr.com/3e4pb

```
/(?:(\|:framework\.urls\.[^:]+:\|)+([^\s\|]*))+/g
```

over this example string:

> |:framework.urls.something:|/hey|:framework.urls.something-else:|.|:framework.urls.com:|/hey-there not included

What I want/expect in the output is 8 groups altogether...

1. |:framework.urls.something:|
2. /hey
3. |:framework.urls.something-else:|
4. (nothing)
5. |:framework.urls.after:|
6. .
7. |:framework.urls.com:|
8. /hey-there

The string at the end ("not included") would not be included in the regex. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? My current implementation seems to only be grabbing the last two groups ("|:framework.urls.com:|" and "/hey-there")

Comment: How can you expect to have 8 groups if your pattern only has 2? Did you mean 8 matches?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew split by `|` and count...

Comment: I was hoping that + on the end of the regex would repeat the groupings, but that's probably not the case

Comment: @user1771700: It is never the case in any regex flavor. So, you need a list of the 1-8 values? Split with `|`.

Comment: User, if you put the *plus* here: `)+)/` than you have 3 nice groups.

Comment: Roko, I know I can do that, but if it's possible with one regex I'd prefer that. We send these strings to translators and I need to create a regex based off of the English text to check against the translations we get back to make sure they didn't change the order/translate any of our text pointers, so dealing with one regex output would be ideal rather than dealing with them piece-wise and combining them in fairly ugly JS.

Comment: Wiktor, I'm not following what you mean... could you give me an example?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/q71adek0/ or https://jsfiddle.net/q71adek0/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '|:framework.urls.something:|/hey|:framework.urls.something-else:||:framework.urls.after:|.|:framework.urls.com:|/hey-there not included';

var re = /(\|:framework\.urls\.[^:]+:\|)([^\s|]+(?=\s|\|:))?/g; 
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) re.lastIndex++;
  console.log(m[1]);
  console.log(m[2]);
}
```

*outputs:*

> |:framework.urls.something:|
>   **/hey**
>   |:framework.urls.something-else:|
>   **undefined**
>   |:framework.urls.after:|
>   **.**
>   |:framework.urls.com:|
>   **/hey-there**

https://regex101.com/r/zD8iZ0/3

**Old** vs **New** For comparison:

```
/(?:(\|:framework\.urls\.[^:]+:\|)+([^\s\|]*))+/g;             // OLD
   /(\|:framework\.urls\.[^:]+:\|)([^\s|]+(?=\s|\|:))?/g;      // NEW
```

I did not "repeated" the capturing group (beside using `g`*lobal* flag) but instead I've made the rules for the second match a bit stricter to look for anything that is not a space or `|`
and than used a positive lookahead for "*followed by* space or `|:`".

The string's "`:||:`" occurrence that's needed to return `"(nothing)"` in my case returns `undefined` (hopefully it's what you were looking for)

Answer (score 0):

No need to be so complex.
You can just globally find individual parts, put into an array.

`(\|:(?:(?!:\||\s).)*:\||[\S\s]*?(?=\|:|$))`

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      \|:
      (?:
           (?! :\| | \s )
           . 
      )*
      :\|
   |  
      [\S\s]*? 
      (?= \|: | $ )
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the + at the end. All it does is makes it greedy and grab everything, which then returns you the last thing. Basically by removing it you solve your issue.

Not to mention `?:` symbolises non-capturing groups - http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Example of what you want: https://regex101.com/r/cR0aG8/8